# Make a \code{...} macro that nerfs as many special chars as possible

Tags: code, typewriter, catcodes, ampersand

This is related to [Simplify the use of ampersand & in glossaries description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316916/simplify-the-use-of-ampersand-in-glossaries-description), but having read those answers and tried something based on them, I'm finding it still doesn't work for my case.

Basically I'm trying to make a macro `\code{...}` that will typeset `...` in monospace font, inline. I guess I'm looking for something fairly similar to WEB's `|...|` syntax, except that `|` would be a fairly bad choice of delimiter character for my purposes.

For example, I want this:

```
To capture a reference to the local variable \code{snake_case},
we write \code{[&snake_case]}.
```

to typeset as if I'd written

```
To capture a reference to the local variable \texttt{snake\_case},
we write \texttt{[\&snake\_case]}.
```

I'm going to be writing a *lot* of inline code snippets, so I'd prefer not to have to remember to backslash-escape any special character if it's at all avoidable.

My attempt so far is:

```
% make _ a non-special character
\usepackage{underscore}

% make & a non-special character
\newcommand{\makeampletter}{\catcode`\&=12\relax}
\newcommand{\makeampother}{\catcode`\&=4\relax}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\makeampletter\texttt{#1}\makeampother}
```

I am vaguely aware of the existence of `\verb|...|`, but answers like [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt) have made me wary of it; I'd rather use something that acts as much like `\texttt` as possible, and where I 100% understand how I'm deviating from `\texttt` when I use it.

(Bonus points for not only fixing my ampersand issue but also addressing my inevitable future issues with `%`, `{`, and `}`.)

Comment: any command based on catcode changes has exactly the same issues as verb so you may as well use verb

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've heard that `\verb` also messes with hyphenation and line-breaking; and that it prints underscores weirdly.

Comment: Nerfs ? What am I missing ?

Comment: don't believe everything you hear. The disabling of hyphenation is a feature of the monospace font setup so applies equally to `\verb` and `\texttt` the issues with verb not working on arguments of other commands are just related to catcode. if you fix the `&` catcode change in your definition and do the same for all the other special characters then you will just have the definition of `\verb`.

Comment: @RobtA: Try adding `\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\let\code\lstinline` to your preamble...

Comment: @Werner: That's a good answer; you should post it! Except that when I do that, I see a bunch of blank space (looks like about an additional quad space) *before* (but not *after*) each inline code snippet.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: [I don't in your small example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbn7K.png). Perhaps you're doing something different?

Comment: Aha, if I remove `\lstset{autodedent}` the extra space goes away. But actually I want to get rid of `basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize` in the inline context as well, or else the text becomes too small when it's inline. Time to read even more of the `listings` manual, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Werner in the comments for this:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,autodedent=0]{#1}}
```

(Notice that `autodedent` is being provided for me by [Jubobs' `lstautodedent` package](https://github.com/Jubobs/lstautodedent/blob/master/lstautodedent.sty).)

My only remaining problems with my `\code` have to do with linebreaking. Namely,

- sometimes I see `foo, \code{bar}, baz` linebreaking between "bar" and ","
- sometimes I see `\code{foo, bar, baz}` linebreaking between "bar" and ","

The former is indefensible; the latter is at least defensible, even if it's ugly. I suspect there are things I could do to improve this answer in those departments.

Comment: Also add `breaklines=false` to your list of options.

Comment: @Werner: `breaklines=false` fixes the latter problem but not the former, right? I actually already fixed the latter by throwing an `\mbox{...}` around the whole thing, although I might change it to `breaklines=false` now.